# Can't import MySQL database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am importing database in phpMyAdmin but having errors. I tried too much but showing same errors, here is SQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `business` (
  `b_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `b_title` text,
  `b_lastmodified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_detail` text,
  `b_banner_image` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_cat_id` int(10) DEFAULT '100',
  `b_subcat_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_tags` text,
  `b_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_isactive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'admin will approve it',
  `b_created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_views` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'number of times this is viewed',
  PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=764 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `business` (`b_id`, `b_title`, `b_lastmodified`, `b_detail`, `b_banner_image`, `b_cat_id`, `b_subcat_id`, `b_tags`, `b_user_id`, `b_isactive`, `b_created_on`, `b_views`) VALUES ('1', 'Couple Names Silver Pendant', '2014-01-15 02:25:02', '', 'itm_couple-names-silver-pendant2013-03-25_22-07-16_1.jpg', '35', '0', 'love pendant,name pictures,silver name pendant,couple name pendant,locket of love,chain of name,fb display photos', '1', '1', '2013-03-25 22:06:53', '7263');
```

And showing these errors:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `business` (

 `b_id` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `b_title` TEXT,
 `b_lastmodified` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
 `b_detail` TEXT,
 `b_banner_image` VARCHAR( 250 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `b_cat_id` INT( 10 ) DEFAULT  '100',
 `b_subcat_id` INT( 10 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `b_tags` TEXT,
 `b_user_id` BIGINT( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `b_isactive` TINYINT( 1 ) DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'admin will approve it',
 `b_created_on` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
 `b_views` BIGINT( 20 ) DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'number of times this is viewed',
PRIMARY KEY (  `b_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =764 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Answer (score 2):

In **phpMyAdmin** make a new database or select an existing database. Then import the SQL file.

or

Include below lines into your first line of the sql script.

```
create database database_name;
use database_name;
```

Comment: Include below lines into your first line of the sql script then only...

use database_name;

Comment: i dit but in my hosting i can't create more database, i have allow only one database

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected a database in which you want to create the table and start the import. This is why you get that error.

You should click on the database you are importing in, before you go to the query window and execute the query.
Another option is to select the database, like this:

```
    USE `database_name`;
    CREATE TABLE `business` (
      `b_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `b_title` text,
      `b_lastmodified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `b_detail` text,
      `b_banner_image` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `b_cat_id` int(10) DEFAULT '100',
      `b_subcat_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `b_tags` text,
      `b_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `b_isactive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'admin will approve it',
      `b_created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `b_views` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'number of times this is viewed',
      PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=764 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `business` (`b_id`, `b_title`, `b_lastmodified`, `b_detail`, `b_banner_image`, `b_cat_id`, `b_subcat_id`, `b_tags`, `b_user_id`, `b_isactive`, `b_created_on`, `b_views`) VALUES ('1', 'Couple Names Silver Pendant', '2014-01-15 02:25:02', '', 'itm_couple-names-silver-pendant2013-03-25_22-07-16_1.jpg', '35', '0', 'love pendant,name pictures,silver name pendant,couple name pendant,locket of love,chain of name,fb display photos', '1', '1', '2013-03-25 22:06:53', '7263');
```

Comment: If so, please consider selecting the answer as the correct one.